# I am looking for a way to set "selectBox" be selected when selectedIndex is unknown

Tags: javascript

I would like to set `YYYY-MM-DD` (that comes from GET parameter)

I can set it by `selectedIndex`
When `selectedIndex` is unknown,
How can I set the default selected box?

I would like to set "the default selected"  by value

e.g  `GET = 2021-08-06` I want it to be selected `2021-08-06`
but `HTML` changes dynamically.

document.getElementById("select_date").selectedIndex = 1;
=> 2021-07-30  will be sleeted.

```
        var param = decodeURIComponent(element[1]);

        document.getElementById("select_date").value = param;
        console.log("param"+param)
//log result = param2021-7-23


 <form method="GET" action="http://">
 <select id="select_date" name="delivery_date">
<option value="2021-07-23">2021-07-23</option>
<option value="2021-07-30">2021-07-30</option>
<option value="2021-08-06">2021-08-06</option>
</select>
```

[image]
When `document.getElementById("select_date").value  = paramValue`
When  `param = "2021-7-23"`; work well then.

[image]

Comment: try `document.getElementById("select_date").val('2021-08-06')`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).val is not a function
    at confirmation?c=3&date=2021-7-23:312
happens

Comment: @conny `val` is not work in pure JavaScript. It is a jQuery syntax. See my answer to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the value of selectbox:

```js
var elemnt = "2021-8-6";

var date = new Date(elemnt);

var format = convertDate(date) 

var seolectedval = decodeURIComponent(format)

document.getElementById("select_date").value = seolectedval;

function convertDate(date) {
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
  var dd  = date.getDate().toString();

  var mmChars = mm.split('');
  var ddChars = dd.split('');

  return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1]?mm:"0"+mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1]?dd:"0"+ddChars[0]);
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="http://">
 <select id="select_date" name="delivery_date">
<option value="2021-07-23">2021-07-23</option>
<option value="2021-07-30">2021-07-30</option>
<option value="2021-08-06">2021-08-06</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: Actually not..  but your insert code works well . but when I use a variable , it does not work.
document.getElementById("select_date").value = param;

Comment: It doesn't relate to variable. please show value of  `element[1]`

Comment: element[1] is 2021-08-06

Comment: element[1] value is string? I updated my answer and still is OK

Comment: I am not sure. as far as I can see ...it seems to be string. That's so weird . When the selectBox.value come from decodeURIComponent(elemnt), it always be blanked.

Comment: I just realised!!!  element[1] value became 2021-8-6 ...

Comment: @conny You can convert the date to desire format. I updated my answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235124/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-conny).